# When I read that a system is located x light years away, why is there no direction?

Tags: space, big-bang-theory, space-time

Well, I just read [an article](http://news.yahoo.com/rare-galaxy-2-black-holes-1-starved-stars-180552639.html) about a galaxy with two black holes, and it stated that the galaxy is 1 billion light-years away. Why is there no direction given? If the Big Bang happened, and things are moving away from each other, we can still have at least two directions - away from the center, and to it. Is that a right way to think about space and our drift in space?

Comment: Since the phrasing of your question also suggests a certain misunderstanding, you might find these useful: [What is in the center of the universe?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/669/) and
[Do we know the exact spot where big bang took place?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/874/do-we-know-the-exact-spot-where-big-bang-took-place).

Answer (score 5):

The galaxy's catalog name, SDSS J1126+2944, also gives its direction. This means the galaxy is at approximately 11h26m right ascension and 29 degrees 44 minutes north declination.

The "full name" of the galaxy, given here:

http://www.sci-news.com/astronomy/pair-black-holes-distant-galaxy-03546.html

is "SDSS J112659.54+294442.8", which gives its position even more precisely. A finder chart is here:

http://simbad.u-strasbg.fr/simbad/sim-id?Ident=SDSS+J112659.54%2B294442.8