# Can we determine our orientation in the universe relative to the origin point of the big bang?

Tags: universe, big-bang-theory

Based on our knowledge of the expansion of the universe, can we trace galaxy movement backwards in order to determine the approximate relative location of the point where the big bang occurred?

The genesis of this question has to do with the Webb images, and how each article explains that we are looking 13 billion years backwards in time to the beginning of the universe.  Every time I hear this I wonder, "but what are we seeing if we look in the *opposite direction*?"  So, I might ask this in a separate question if appropriate, but a good answer to this question would also clarify this point...

Comment: No, because the Big Bang wasn’t an event that happened at any single point. On some level the expansion of space is occurring everywhere.

Comment: @user438383, is that an answer, or a comment?

Comment: Please see https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/136860/123208 & https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/874/16685

Comment: That question isn't an exact duplicate of this one, but it's pretty close, and I think it covers what you're asking.

Comment: Yep, I agree they are close enough to my question to provide the answer I was looking for.  Thanks.